# VictoriaMetrics return different results from sum query and value counted from samples

Tags: prometheus, promql, grafana-loki, victoriametrics

I have metric from Grafana Loki named `logs_bytes_over_time` and have two labels:

- **interval** - define average value for defined interval `1m`
- **service** - name of service logs belongs to

All services have some retention and `app1` and `app2` has retention 336 hours (14 days). When count sum over time, the result show `8gb` for app1 and `5gb` for app2:

```
curl http://victoria-metrics:8428/prometheus/api/v1/query -d 'query=sum_over_time(logs_bytes_over_time{interval="1m", service=~"app.*"}[14d])' | jq .
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "resultType": "vector",
    "result": [
      {
        "metric": {
          "interval": "1m",
          "service": "app1"
        },
        "value": [
          1672315519,
          "8593470346"
        ]
      },
      {
        "metric": {
          "interval": "1m",
          "service": "app2"
        },
        "value": [
          1672315519,
          "5498422093"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I get metrics value from Victoria Metrics API since last 336 hours, I received different values:

- app1 - `42.33gb`
- app2 - `20.87gb`

The result is from samples downloaded from Victoria metrics API:

```
curl http://victoria-metrics:8428/prometheus/api/v1/query_range -d 'query=logs_bytes_over_time{interval="1m", service=~"app.*"}' -d 'start=Xh' -d 'stop=Yh' -d 'step=1m'
```

Where X and Y are iterate over 24h interval to make requests easier for Victoria Metrics. This is pairs of X and Y I iterate over:

```py
[('-336h', '-312h'), ('-312h', '-288h'), ('-288h', '-264h'), ('-264h', '-240h'), ('-240h', '-216h'), ('-216h', '-192h'), ('-192h', '-168h'), ('-168h', '-144h'), ('-144h', '-120h'), ('-120h', '-96h'), ('-96h', '-72h'), ('-72h', '-48h'), ('-48h', '-24h'), ('-24h', '0')]
```

What I do is just sum all the values I received. I sum it with python and bash to be sure, I did not make any mistake in script, the results are the same.

Why the sum of values from Victoria API and from query `sum_over_time` are so different? I would expect the result should be the same, or at least much closer to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [/api/v1/query_range](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query) doesn't return **raw samples** stored in VictoriaMetrics. It returns **calculated** values at timestamps `t=[start, start+step, start+2*step, ..., end]`. More specifically, it returns the last raw sample value on a time range `(t-scrape_interval ... t]` per each timestamp `t` from the list above, where `scrape_interval` is the median interval between **raw samples**. Note that the `t-scrape_interval` isn't included in the time range, while `t` is included. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#range-query) for more details.

The `sum_over_time(m[d])` returns the sum of **raw samples** on the time range `(t-d ... t]` when queried at the timestamp `t`. See [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#sum_over_time) for more details.

It is likely the interval between **raw samples** in the queried time series exceeds the `step` value passed to `/api/v1/query_range`. This results in duplicate output values per each **raw sample** stored in VictoriaMetrics.

VictoriaMetrics provides export APIs, which can be used for exporting **raw samples** for the given time series - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#how-to-export-time-series) and [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/analyzing-prometheus-data-with-external-tools-5f3e5e147639) for details. Try exporting raw samples with these APIs and verifying whether the sum of **raw samples** matches the value returned by `sum_over_time(m[d])`.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I test it with exported json, and sum_over_time function and sum samples from export returns the same results.